# PhotoChooserTask: know where does the photo come from

Tags: windows-phone-7, camera

I'm using PhotoChooserTask with showCamera set to true. My question is if it is possible to know where the photo comes from: the library or the user has taken a new photo.
What I want is to send the coordinates if the photo has just been taken.
I know I could put two buttons, one for choosing from the library and another to take a new photo, but I'd prefer to have it in a single button.

Thank you!

Comment: I've tried to compare the original photo name in both cases and no differences to have a clue. I suppose it's not possible to know as there are no answers...

Answer (score 0):

Does the photo contain EXIF metadata?   Perhaps you could read the photo stream and load the EXIF metadata and figure out pic time, GPS coords, etc.